# whenever i move my laptop, it loses all internet connection and said internet connection stops working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I am running windows 10 pro in my ASUS TUF Gaming A15, and recently whenever I move my laptop just a tiny bit, my WIFI stops working. I know its not the router because it happens with my phone hotspot too. Because it frustrated me so much, I reinstalled windows completely from a official boot stick, and the same problem still occurs, followed a million tutorials and still nothing, if there is something wrong with my hardware, please tell my how to check and possibly find a solution.

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem, specifically, I adequate EMI protection.  What type of WiFi adapter do you have specifically?

Comment: Or a loose connection to the WiFi module or power.